# android xml drawable parameters

Tags: android, xml, parameter-passing, drawable

Is it possible to have an xml drawable with parameters?  Suppose I have an xml drawable that I want to reuse for the rounded corners, gradients etc, and the only variable is a color or two.  Is it possible to specify/pass parameters to an xml drawable?

Comment: Dont understand what you want

Comment: Dr. nik.  lets say you have a less than trivial xml drawable that contains rounded corners, a solid outline, and a gradient (perhaps in a layer list).  I just want to have say a green, yellow & red version of what is otherwise an identical drawable.  make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can derive your own class from Drawable, have a constructor accepting the parameters you want to make adjustable and in the constructor first call `createFromXML` passing your xml and then setup those adjustable parameters.
I didn't try that myself, perhaps, I'm wrong

Comment: I was just going to ask the same question. Did this solution work? Is there a sample?
Mine is quite trivial and I could duplicate the XML for each required colour, but it's not an elegant sol'n.