# Android drawable with parameters

Tags: android

Is it possible to have something like

**drawable/myshape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="{0}" />
</shape>
```

and then from java class take this drawable passing values for parameters. Something like

```
Drawable myshape = ???.getDrawableWithParameters(R.drawable.myshape, 0x00ff00);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396779/android-xml-drawable-parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `shape` the way you have shown in the example, then it will be accessible as a [`GradientDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html).

```
GradientDrawable d = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourid);
```

If you take a look at the documentation (link above) you can see all the functions, you can access from a `GradientDrawable` object. You can also set the background and border color and width later, programmatically using this object.

**I'm not 100% sure, that every time you create a shape in xml, you will get a `GradientDrawable`**. I needed to modifiy some properties on a shape myself, and figured it out seeing ClassCastExceptions when trying to cast to other types of `Drawable`s

Comment: It's not about the shape. It could be a layer list. The parameters is what i ask for. If there is a way we could pass parameters in drawable like we do in strings

Comment: Do you want to pass parameters like colors and sizes to a drawable only using its id and and the parameters you like? No, i don't think thats possible. That would violate the oop principles, that every java developer should follow (in my opinion), and would be completely unnecessary, because all these Drawable subclasses have a really friendly interface to handle those things.